Перевернуть текст наоборот
Как можно сделать так чтобы (стрингом) поворачивать слова наоборот, но чтобы они оставались на своем месте, например
"Привет друг" > "тевирп груд"

Ну по логике так - найти  индексы начала и конца слова, и перевернуть кусок строки между данными индексами

Этот вопрос похож на: перевернуть каждое слово в строке. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

var string = "Привет друг";
var words = string.split(" "); // массив слов
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    words[i] = words[i]
        .split("") // массив букв
        .reverse() // перевернутый массив
        .join(""); // строка из массива
}
var reversed = words.join(" "); // соединяем все слова в одну строку
console.log(reversed);


интересно спасибо

вопрос , а для чего нужны точки перед  сплит реверс и джоин ?

Это такие методы

Что бы перевернуть все буквы в словах, при этом оставив сами слова на своем месте, надо:
Превратить строку в массив слов
Каждое слово превратить в массив букв
Массив букв перевернуть
Превратить массив букв в строку
Превратить массив перевернутых слов в строку


const a = 'Привет друг';
const res = a.split(' ') // Превращаем строку в массив слов
  .map(i => i.split('') // Каждое слово превращаем в массив букв
    .reverse() // Переворачиваем буквы в слове
    .join('') // Собираем строку из массива
  )
  .join(' '); // Массив слов превращаем в строку

console.log(res)




спасибо , функция мап , мне вообще не было знакомо )

@maksimvolkov Это один из самых популярных методов переборов массивов, наравне с forEach. Почитайте на досуге про методы массивов - очень полезно будет

спасибо , займусь этим сейчас )
